# Need to run soql as admin in apex controller

Tags: apex, soql

I need to run an SOQL command, as admin just like system.runAs(u) in controller.

Is there a way to do this.

Comment: Can you describe your reason for needing to run code with such elevated credentials?

Comment: Hey apex run in system context so it does NLT depend whether u run as admin or not. If you are having some prob. In running or require extra permission be sure to check with sharing keyword should not be there

Answer (score 15, accepted):

To run a query as "an administrator", use the "without sharing" keyword within a class:

```
public without sharing class Utility {
    public static Account[] queryAccounts() {
        return [SELECT Id, Name, Industry FROM Account LIMIT 100];
    }
}
```

While you are still running the query as the current user, the current user's sharing is ignored, which means that the query will execute *as if* the user were an administrator.

Also note that within triggers, the code runs by default "without sharing", so it is generally not necessary to run "as administrator" unless you're using utility classes (such as the example here).

Comment: I have the same issue and the answer from **sfdcfox** works beautiful. I have a class that when is executed by admin bring all the data but for others user just bring their own information. With **without Sharing** at the beginning of the class the current user's sharing is ignored. Thanks to **sfdcfox** for the solution...

Answer (score 8):

There is **NO** way to do this outside of test methods and for good reason.

### In Test Methods:

By default the code will likely be running as an admin user. What you can do though is grab the profile ID for the 'System Administrator' profile, insert a new user using that profile, then run as the new user.

```
Id profileId = [select Id from UserProfile where Name = 'System Administrator' limit 1].Id

User u = new User();
// fill in required fields (well documented)
u.UserProfileId = profileId; // think this is the right field name, double check
insert u;

System.RunAs(u.Id);
```

Comment: but how to run as new user?

Comment: I got an error. System.runAs can only be used within a test method:

Comment: Oh sorry. I assumed you meant in a test method. There is no way to run code as another user otherwise as that would potentially be a huge security breach.

Comment: do you really need to run as another user, or just with System privileges ? how about using without sharing ?

Answer (score 1):

Yes as the error suggest, the

> System.runAs()

method can be used only in Test Classes.
As @LaceySnr suggested, all APEX code run with "**View All**" and "**Modify All**" permissions.

If your apex classes have "**With Sharing**" Keyword, then all the Sharing rules for logged-in user apply.