# want to query all ContentDocument without changing permission "Query All Files: Allows View All Data"

Tags: soql, query, permissions, permission-sets, files

I want to run the following SOQL and want to get all the ContentDocument from all users.

```
SELECT OwnerId, Title, FileType, LatestPublishedVersionId, ContentModifiedDate, CreatedDate FROM ContentDocument
```

But actually, the result ContentDocument is only the ones which owner is mine.
If I change `Query All Files` in Setting (※1), I can see all data but its not good in terms of security because for enabling `Query All Files`, users need to read other objects (for example, Accounts, Contacts).
I want normal user (not System Administrator) to see Files.
How can I do this without the `Query All Files` in Setting?

※1 [Obtaining all ContentDocument records using SOQL](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/2206/obtaining-all-contentdocument-records-using-soql)

Comment: this can help https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/18867/need-to-run-soql-as-admin-in-apex-controller

Comment: oh thank you. I can SELECT after changing `with sharing` to `without sharing`